# How can I add items down to be able to scroll?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-transforms

How can I add items down to be able to scroll?

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why i get minuses?

Comment: I didn't downvote but I think it's because questions should show some effort. Whenever someone asks just for code, they get downvoted. Also, your question isn't very clear. You just showed a image but I don't know what you want from the image. What is span1, 2 and 3? Do you want to add the items to the bottom? or the top?

Comment: @Andrew Yes. I want to add elements from below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a hack using `transform: scaleY(-1)` to start adding elements from the bottom

1. `transform: scaleY(-1)` on the container to invert it vertically
2. `transform: scaleY(-1)` on the children of the container to rectify the inversion on the children.
3. Even the overflow for the container starts from the bottom!

See demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}
.wrapper > div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 50vh;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 10px auto;
  transform: scaleY(-1);
  /*align text inside*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

Comment: OperaMini and EI8 - not support

Answer (score 0):

Is this what u mean?

```
<div style="overflow-y:scroll;, height: 5px;">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <!-- any number of elements you want-->
</div>
```

Comment: are you trying to focus onto the `padding` thing or the `stack` form for spans?

Comment: I do chat. Span it - `<span>Message</span>` . I want messages add from the bottom